# How can I manage dev and prod environment for a telegram bot?

Tags: telegram-bot

I made a bot which users already use and now I'm curious how can I continue developing it, without breaking something on the users' side.

The only way I know atm is to create another bot just for dev purposes and use its token. But I don't really like this approach, cause this bot can be found through the search.

Are there any other ways and best practices known?

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking of creating 2 bots e.g. `my_bot` and `my_dev_bot` and using them as such "environments" (because they are 2 tokens). I can run `my_dev_bot` from my local machine and instantly play with new functionality, then, deploy the same code for `my_bot` in production.